# Multiple role handling for a single user in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having a trouble time now as my client wants multiple role access for a single user with all the security in place. How can I do it in Codeigniter? I am not using any Authentication library. Let me explain the issue in detail.
Example:

If an employee's assigned primary role is Sales Coordinator. At some point, he has to be assigned another role of Sales Supervisor along with his primary role. so when this employee login with his primary role, in his menu the Sales supervisors Menus should also be active.

When logged in as Sales Coordinator(single role), the menu list would be:

```
Sales 
Customers Details
```

But when he is assigned an additional role (Sales Supervisor), his menu would also be active in the sales coordinators Home Menu as follows:

```
Sales
Customers Details
Reports
Manage Staff
```

This would be the new menu once the sales coordinator is logged in with his login credentials to his Panel. There is no different logins for this staff for two different roles assigned.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168729/codeigniter-managing-user-roles

Comment: create table like (User role or permissions), on the login time get all permissions on table and and show menu on the basis of permissions in view

Comment: if you need more explanation i give you details in only tabular form

Comment: Load the roles as an array, and check is_exist always

Comment: @ Bilal Ahmed-- can we change this permisssions in furture and reassign  permission to some other staff? I want to have this role change provision editable.

Comment: @ Bhaskar-- I checked it earlier, but bad luck for me.. the link was not working.

Comment: @ Bilal Ahmed --- Can you please give me  a tabular view..

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @ halfer---Yeah..will take care of that next time... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The scope of this question is probably beyond a single Stack Overflow post. But as some have mentioned, one way is to establish a many to many relationship with the user table, role table and functions table. This way, you can define which users have which roles, and in turn, which functions each role is permitted to perform.

Similar to this image from the YiiFramework
[image]

http://www.yiiframework.com/tutorial/image?type=guide&version=1.1&lang=en&file=has_many_through.png

You might have tables such as:

```
CREATE TABLE [Users]
(
    [UserID] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Username] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [Roles]
(
    [RoleID] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    [RoleTitle] NVARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE [UserRoles]
(
    [UserID] INT,
    [RoleID] INT
);
```